# Add observable to existing Subject

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have an observable (Angular Subject) called `event$`. When screens are loaded I want to add DOM controls as emitters to this observable. The observable will already have subscribers. I'm achieving this by subscribing to an observable based on the control with the existing `event$` as below. (Subscription management details omitted for clarity.)

shared service:

```
private _event$: Subject<Event> = new Subject();
public addEventEmitter(event: Observable<Event>) {
  event.subscribe(this._event$);
}
```

component code:

```
@ViewChild('leftSide', { read: ElementRef }) leftSide: ElementRef;

const leftClick$: Observable<Event> = fromEvent(this.leftSide.nativeElement, 'click');
this.comms.addEventEmitter(leftClick$.pipe(mapTo(anEvent)));
```

I'm having, possibly unrelated, issues with an `ion-toggle` control intermittently showing the incorrect state. Is this a reasonable method of merging an observable with one that already has subscribers?  Would I be better off having an `onChange` or click event call `event$.next()`? To my mind combining the observables is more reactive whereas calling the next method on the `event$` for each control interaction is very imperative.

Answer (score 3):

Disregarding the simplicity and the elegance of being able to write `event.subscribe(this._event$);`, this is not a good idea. From what I noticed by doing this, is that whenever your `_event$` completes, the `event` will also complete, which I don't think is the behavior you want. You're better off emitting the value manually like this:

```
event.subscribe(e => this._event$.next(e));
```

And even though you said you omitted the subscription management details, I feel it's important to mention again that you need to manage this subscription in order to avoid memory leaks.